# org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext from [Module "deployment.RGWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Tags: java, wildfly

i am using wildfly 10.1.0 and i am trying to run my web project but i am getting following error

```html
12:49:17,589 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "RGWeb.war" (runtime-name: "RGWeb.war")
12:49:18,047 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."RGWeb.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."RGWeb.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "RGWeb.war"
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
 at org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFManagedBeanProcessor.deploy(JSFManagedBeanProcessor.java:100)
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
 ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext from [Module "deployment.RGWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
 at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
 ... 11 more

12:49:18,048 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "RGWeb.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGWeb.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGWeb.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"RGWeb.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext from [Module \"deployment.RGWeb.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGWeb.war\".POST_MODULE"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
12:49:18,071 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "RGWeb.war" (runtime-name : "RGWeb.war")
12:49:18,071 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGWeb.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."RGWeb.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "RGWeb.war"
```

can you help me out with this

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are missing spring libraries in your classpath. Try to put spring libraries in the classpath of your webapp : WEB-INF/lib.

Using maven deployment can often help in such cases by just adding dependencies. Try to take a look at this page : http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/maven-configuration-for-java-ee-7-projects-on-wildfly

Comment: i have all libraries in my D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\lib\ext folder and also in modules\common\lib folder and i am not using maven i am using and to build and deploy project.

Comment: And do you find some libraries named with the pattern spring*.jar. Did you check that your classpath has the two directories that you stated.

Comment: Try adding spring libraries in the WEB-INF/lib of your war file not the classpath from the server

Comment: is there any way i can reference my libraries in wildfly folder to war folder

Comment: ok i have added libraries to my WEB-INF\lib folder that error got away but new arise take a look at this

Comment: If you have a new error mark this question as answered and do a new question. Then post a comment to my answer I'll take a look

Comment: thanks  Christophe i added all jars in my webinf\lib folder and i get rid of that error.